# Are there materials with an adiabatic compressibility higher than that of common gases?

Tags: thermodynamics

Are there materials with an adiabatic compressibility, measured at atmospheric pressure, higher than that of common gases? Is there any fundamental upper limit to the differential compressibility of matter that is under a given positive pressure?

Answer (score 1):

For ideal gases, $k_s$, the adiabatic compressibility is proportional to the inverse of the density and temperature, but independent of the pressure (see http://www.chem.arizona.edu/~salzmanr/480a/480ants/kapsadex/kapsadex.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound). So there is no upper limit for an ideal gas: you can diminish   $T$ and $\rho$   to make $k_s$ as high as you want. However, for real gases you should expect this not to be exactly true. I am not aware of any specific upper limit that has been extrapolated from measurements or theoretically calculated from improvements to the ideal gas model.